# Resolving all symbolic links in NSURL

Tags: cocoa, path, nsurl, symlink, symlink-traversal

I'm writing a little piece of code in which I should detect if an `NSURL` contains a symbolic link (i.e., symbolic file components other than the last one should also be detected). To do this, I confront the `NSURL` itself with the `NSURL` returned by `-URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath`. The problem is that this method seems to return all symbolic links in lowercase. Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: What's the problem with it returning resolved symlinks in lowercase?

Comment: Did you try `-[NSString stringByResolvingSymlinksInPath]`? Does it have the same “bug”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either I really did something wrong or this bug was fixed with the latest Mountain Lion update. Now all symlinks are correctly resolved.

Answer (score 4):

You can traverse symlinks manually:

1. Detect symbolic link using `-[NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:error:]` and in key `NSFileType` search for `NSFileTypeSymbolicLink` value.
2. Get destination path using `-[NSFileManager destinationOfSymbolicLinkAtPath:error:]` and append them.

Repeat this for every path component.

Comment: Thanks, this would have been my choice if I didn't notice the bug was resolved!